# Invalid Security Cert error when using Python Selenium WebDriver with Firefox GeckoDriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, ssl, geckodriver

I'm updating the version of Firefox we use for our in house Selenium tests. As part of this I know I need to use the GeckoDriver, in a similar way that we need to use the ChromeDriver for Chrome. It seems to be all plumbed in but the Software Under Test uses a self signed ssl cert, which will give you the "untrusted" cert warning before proceeding. In order to work around this, I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
firefox_log = "<path to firefox log>"

DRIVER = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=<path to gecko driver exe>, capabilities=capabilities, log_path=firefox_log)
```

However, when the tests run, it does run/open Firefox, but it instantly errors with he following:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:certerror?e=nssBadCert&u=https%3A//10.10.10.10/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=10.10.10.10%20uses%20an%20invalid%20security%20certificate.%0A%0AThe%20certificate%20is%20not%20trusted%20because%20it%20is%20self-signed.%0AThe%20certificate%20is%20only%20valid%20for%20%3Ca%20id%3D%22cert_domain_link%22%20title%3D%22amnesiac%22%3Eamnesiac%3C/a%3E%0A%0AError%20code%3A%20%3Ca%20id%3D%22errorCode%22%20title%3D%22SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%22%3ESEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%3C/a%3E%0A
```

I know that there was a bug in this area but I was under the impression it was fixed. Am I missing something?

Version Info:

- Firefox Version: 51.0.1
- GeckoDriver Version: 0.14.0
- Selenium Version: 3.0.2

Comment: I have also tried using "acceptInsecureCerts" instead of "acceptSslCerts" and I get the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I to am facing this issue, trying to get this capability to work for me in .NET. But I did notice you are using Firefox 51.0.1. While the bug fix for this has been live since (I beileve) GeckoDriver 0.11.0 it was dependent on the fix of a bug in Firefox which according to the [original bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196) it was `VERIFIED FIXED in Firefox 52`. So I would try updating Firefox since 52 became the stable release 3/7/2016. Hope that helps.

Comment: Regarding with what you mentioned Joshua, I'm also working with .NET. I updated Firefox to version 52 yesterday and suddenly I cannot access SSL web sites in localhost through IIS Express. I've tried to export IIS Express certificate and import it as CA in Firefox but it doesn't allow to do it. I've verified that if I go back to Firefox 51, the website is working again. Do you have the same issue?

Comment: I have not tried the profile workaround for this for unsecured sites. I might have to go down that road though if I cant figure out how to set these capabilities during driver initialization. For the time being I have my test nodes all running Firefox 46 so I dont have to use Marionette driver, but this is increasingly becoming a bigger problem.

Comment: I upgraded to 52. I then ensured I used the Capabilities route to trigger the fix as per the developers blog (https://www.hskupin.info/2017/01/23/using-selenium-and-webdriver-to-interact-with-insecure-ssl-pages-in-firefox/). I now see something else.

Now I get the following error:
`WebDriverException: Message: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/v_/jr5_8tpj62z0fx14nsbyb_fm0000gp/T/tmpV0GVtz If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`

This appears to be this bug:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2739

Comment: Newer versions of Selenium and GeckoDriver are now available... I'll try those.